# Font size not changing in HTML

Tags: html, css, fonts, size

So, after I tried all the answers in the forums over here, the font size of my webpage won't change. Here's what I currently have:
`<font size="40px" face="Didot">Hello</font>`
Okay, it will set to 40px, but if I try to make another one using 20px it won't change the font size:
`<font size="20px" face="Didot">World</font>`

Whole code for those who want to check for themselves

```
<html>
<font size="40px" face="Didot">Hello</font>
<font size="20px" face="Didot">World</font>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`<font>` tag is deprecated. ( https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/font )

Use CSS styling instead. See the example below.

```css
.size40 {
  font: 40px/1.5 Didot, serif;
}

.size20 {
  font: 20px/1.5 Didot, serif;
}
```

```html
<span class="size40">Hello</span>
<span class="size20">World</span>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the support, and the inclusion of the website 
Should work, I'll try replace some stuff and see if it works! Already feeling confident about it.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for ways to do inline styling you can follow this approach

```html
<html>
<div style="font-size:40px; font-family:Didot">Hello</div>
<div style="font-size:20px; font-family:Didot">World</div>
</html>
```

But I would recommend to create a separate css file and define styles there. And import those styles in your html using script tags

Answer (score 0):

As said in the previous answer the source is deprecated but if you insists on wanting to try you can use the following:

```
<font face="Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif" size="+7">Hello</font>
<font face="Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif" size="+4">World</font>
```

If it still doesn't work, use CSS:

```
<p>Hello</p>
<p>World</p>
```

⠀

```
p:nth-child(1){
   font-family: Didot;
   font-size: 40px;
}
p:nth-child(2){
   font-family: Didot;
   font-size: 20px;
}
```